# use array table in PHP to JSON

Tags: php, json

I want to send an array table from PHP to JSON.
my array table is simple:

> [0] => 10
>
> [1] => 20

I want to see it in Json as

> { "values":["10","20"] }

In PHP, I tried

```
  $values=array("10","20");
  echo(
         '{
            "values": '.$values.',
            "text": "abcdef"
         }'
  );
```

But it displays:
{ "values":Array] }

Do you know how I can do this ?
(Values in my arrays are not always with a size of 2, it can evolve depending, so I don't want to use values[0] and values[1].

Comment: you really don't need to write json string by hand you know, there's `json_encode` for that

Comment: Create an array, and encode it using json_encode. There are plenty of examples here and on the php main site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)** -  Returns the JSON representation of a value

```
$arr = [10,20];
$newArray = [
     'values' => $arr,
     'text'   => 'abcd'
];
echo $json = json_encode($newArray);
```

Comment: Just echo the json_encode function directly there's no need to initiate a new variable

Comment: What is the advantage of that?

Comment: Where are you going to use the $json variable? nothing right?

Comment: This is for the explanation purpose only, it's on OP to use direct or with variable, may be in the middle of the code he needs same value